# SSIS package could not open global shared memory to communicate with performance DLL

Tags: ssis, package

I am working on a `.dtsx` file that reads from a database and outputs a flat file.

While testing the package, using SQL's Execute Package Utility, I got this warning:

```
Warning:
  Could not open global shared memory to communicate with performance DLL; 
  data flow performance counters are not available.  
  To resolve, run this package as an administrator, 
  or on the system's console.
```

In my research I got mixed messages as to how to deal with this.

One person said it is an issue with data types between the source and data conversion.

Another said it was merely a warning that can be ignored as long as you don't need performance counters (which I don't believe I do).

I also found where it is an issue on computers running Windows XP with no SQL Service packs, but I am on Windows 7.

Should I be concerned with this warning?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My understanding is that is UAC not allowing VS/BIDS access to the performance counters. For day-to-day package execution, you are fine. It is not impacting the ability of SSIS to run nor does it alter the outcome of data transformations.

Comment: After getting to package to function properly (I had to correct a connection string) I can verify that the warning can be ignored and the package will still work (at least in my case).

Comment: yes still valid on VS-2019. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to prevent this warning from occurring, you can add the user account used to execute the package (e.g. your account and/or the SQL Server Agent account) into the local group  "Performance Monitor Users".

If this change is made for any services e.g. SQL Server Agent, the service will need to be restarted for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 3):

The @Nathan fix didn't work for me

What sorted it was running Visual Studio as administrator ... even though my account is in Local Administrators group

Answer (score 1):

The "local administrators" group allows you to function with administrator rights when separately requested, such as "run as administrator". It does not mean that you run everything all the time with administrator rights

Answer (score 0):

In my example, I had an oledb command object but I didn’t have an object preceeding it.  It was doing a single insert statement but   So I added an object just with “Select 1 as NeededColumnInput” and then I connected it to the oledb command object.  Then mine worked.